# Транслитерация полей SQL-запросом

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть необходимость перевести содержимое полей `user_login`, `user_nicename` MySQL базы данных в латиницу, то есть перевести `Иван` и `Ivan`.
Есть ли такая возможность простым SQL-запросом ?

Comment: Количество replace = количеству букв алфавита. Запрос простой, но громоздкий.

Comment: В ответе на дубликат нет подходящего ответа, зато он есть там в самом вопросе..